# Does bootstrapped sample outcome variable link up with x values in regression in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, sample

I am trying to run a regression on a bootstrapped sample in R.

The original sample looks like this dataframe (referred to as df) and has hundreds of entries. Y is the outcome variable, and treat is 0 or 1.

```
y  treat
3  0
5  1
2  0
4  1
```

I have sampled with replacement to generate 900 observations from df$y.

```
set.seed(5)
b1 <- sample(df$y, 900, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
```

I have then run the following regression.

```
lm(b1 ~ treat, df)
```

When using the sample b1 as the outcome in the regression, does this automatically match up the correct value of b1 with the treat value from the original dataframe? If I want the outcome values in b1 to correspond to the correct treat value from the original dataframe, do I need to do something differently? How can I check that this is the regression I am trying to run?

Comment: Now, the lengths are different.  May be you need `df1 <- df[sample(seq_len(nrow(df)), 900, replace = TRUE),]; lm(y ~ treat, df1)`

Comment: The regression I have currently runs even without doing that. What is happening when it runs? I'm surprised its running with different lengths. Edit: The original sample happens to also be 900, which explains why it's running. The regression is wrong but the lengths are the same.

Comment: the example you showed is giving me error for `lm(b1 ~ treat, df)`

Comment: if the lengths are same, then it should work. i.e. if original sampel have 900 rows , and you want to only sample 'y

Comment: It runs but I believe it is not what I am trying to do because I want each specific Y value to accurately correspond to the treat value of 0 or 1 from the original sample. Please let me know if there is something I am not understanding.

Comment: in that case, if you do the sample on the sequence of rows, it would not break that because you are expanding the data basesd on the row sequence where the row is the unit,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `sample` on the sequence of rows instead of a single column.  In the OP's code, it is just sampling the 'y', leaving the 'treat' with just 4 elements and when we apply the formula method, this would result in error as one of the object is having different length.

```
lm(b1 ~ treat, df)
```

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = b1 ~ treat, data = df,
>   drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
>         variable lengths differ (found for 'treat')

Instead, we `sample` on the sequence of rows

```
set.seed(5)
df1 <- df[sample(seq_len(nrow(df)), 900, replace = TRUE),]
lm(y ~ treat, df1)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(y = c(3L, 5L, 2L, 4L), treat = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: @melbez `nrow` should also work, but there are some edge cases